# Finding a substring using C# with a twist

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string that contains the numerous tags of the following form:

```
<: Entity.FieldGroup.FieldName [| Modifier] :>
```

I need to find the tags and replace them with some value(s). So for example the text I have might look as follows:

```
Blah <: Person.Meta.Age :> blah <:       PERSON.meTA.Dependants | CommaList :>
```

and when replaced look like:

```
Blah 30 blah Harry, Mary, John
```

Now the issues are that:

- There may be different amounts of whitespace after and before the opening and closing tags (<: and :>)
- Things may be entered in different case Person vs PERSON, Meta vs meTA
- I cannot "affect" the text around the tags
- There is no predetermined list of tag names ie. Tomorrow might bring Animal.Kind for instance

So from a performance point of view what is the best approach here to extract the tags so I can replace them?

I am concerned that as I replace tags the length of the string I am replacing into changes and thus any offsets won't work and so on. Any suggestions on how to achieve the above elegantly?

Comment: can you give a clear example and not just state the rules

Comment: I suggest [this overload of `Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475.aspx)

Comment: This looks a lot like a markup language... the natural solution to that is a markup language parser.  This seems far too broad to be a sensible question - there are plenty of markup language parsers to study for example.  Otherwise, the rules you've given form an insufficient description of the syntax for anyone to provide useful answers.  Even if they did, this would sound too much like a "do my work" type of question. Regex *might* work, but it is probably the wrong solution.  Looks like the work of a clever fellow who decided to try to rewrite XML instead of just using something standard...

Comment: The reason this is not XML is that this is ultimately user entered so has to be as simple as possible. It also has to be succinct so using XML is not really an option. So if you can recommend something "standard" that can be user entered without the complexity of parsing valid XML then I would like to hear it. And no it is not a "do my work" question either ;-)

Comment: You're making end-users write in a markup language?  The obvious solution to that is... don't.  Without better understanding what problem you are trying to solve, it is difficult to suggest anything more precise.  If your users are generating templates you can still use XML without needing them to type it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach to get the tokens you requested so you can do the replacement.

The .NET Fiddle is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6bX0Db

First, here's a method that uses a regex to identify the matching tokens:

```
public Token[] GetTokens(string input)
{
    string pattern = @"<:[\W]*[\w\d]+\.[\w\d]+\.[\w\d]+[\W]*(|[\W]*[\w\d]+)?[\W]*:>";
    var tokens = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select(m => new Token(m.Value))
        .ToArray();
    return tokens;
}
```

Then, I created a `Token` object that parses the matching tags into the entity field and the modifier if supplied.

```
public class Token
{
    public string TokenToReplace { get; set; }
    public string EntityField { get; set; }
    public string Modifier { get; set; }
    public Token(string tag)
    {
        this.TokenToReplace = tag;
        this.EntityField = Regex.Match(tag, @"[\w\d]+\.[\w\d]+\.[\w\d]+").Value;
        this.Modifier = tag.Contains("|") ? Regex.Match(tag.Split('|').Last(), @"[\w\d]+").Value : null;
    }
}
```

This yielded output for me of:

```
Field: Person.Meta.Age, Modifier: , Orig: <: Person.Meta.Age :>
Field: PERSON.meTA.Dependants, Modifier: CommaList, Orig: <:       PERSON.meTA.Dependants | CommaList :>
```

From here, you have an array of matching tokens with the entity fields and the modifiers isolated. With a basic strategy or proxy pattern, you should be able to apply your existing replacement logic with your modifiers and tokens that can be replaced. I would just iterate with a straight `String.Replace` of the `TokenToReplace` value with the output of the modifier/tag replacement logic.

Comment: That is awesome and works nicely!!!! If possible could I have a small modification? Namely that I could enter multiple modifiers separated with a semi colon so "CommaList;Modifier2;Modifier3".  I am marking it as an answer as I realise I am asking for extra functionality.

Comment: Here's a .NET Fiddle with the new requirement (https://dotnetfiddle.net/tQJCdE). I changed the regex that was matching against the modifiers to include semicolons and whitespace on the front and back of the semicolon since you mentioned this was user-entered. I also modified the Token object and constructor so that it  saves the modifiers as a string array instead of just a string

Comment: That also worked a charm.... I owe you a beer or few ;-)