# How remove some special words from a string content?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have some strings containing code for emoji icons, like `:grinning:`, `:kissing_heart:`, or `:bouquet:`. I'd like to process them to remove the emoji codes.

For example, given:

> Hello:grinning: , how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet:

I want to get this:

> Hello , how are you? Are you fine?

I know I can use this code:

```
richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(":kissing_heart:", "").Replace(":bouquet:", "").Replace(":grinning:", "").ToString();
```

However, there are 856 different emoji icons I have to remove (which, using this method, would take 856 calls to `Replace()`). Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Would a lookup table solve your problem?

Comment: @demonplus: your referenced link talks about removing empji characters while this quesrtion talks about emoji char sequences.

Comment: If you just want to replace emoji with string.empty, you can define an array that contains all emoj strings and then replace them with string.empty

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use Regex to match the word between `:anything:`. Using `Replace` with function you can make other validation.

```
string pattern = @":(.*?):";
string input = "Hello:grinning: , how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet: Are you super fan, for example. :words not to replace:";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, (m) =>
{
    if (m.ToString().Split(' ').Count() > 1) // more than 1 word and other validations that will help preventing parsing the user text
    {
        return m.ToString();
    }
    return String.Empty;
}); // "Hello , how are you? Are you fine? Are you super fan, for example. :words not to replace:"
```

If you don't want to use `Replace` that make use of a lambda expression, you can use `\w`, as  @yorye-nathan mentioned, to match only words.

```
string pattern = @":(\w*):";
string input = "Hello:grinning: , how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet: Are you super fan, for example. :words not to replace:";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, String.Empty); // "Hello , how are you? Are you fine? Are you super fan, for example. :words not to replace:"
```

Comment: `:(\w*):` might be more appropriate

Comment: Do you think this is safe enough?

Comment: You would end up not allowing user write anything between colons.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen The chances are very low that a user will write only a word between `:`

Comment: Should be fine if using `Replace` that takes function as parameter to check if detected word between `:` is indeed one to replace.

Comment: Thank you @AlexeiLevenkov  for helping me to improve my answer.

Comment: Just use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx and match based like
HashSet<string> validEmoji; // store all valid emoji patterns here
(m) => validEmoji.Contains(m.ToString()) ? String.Empty : m.ToString()

Comment: @YoryeNathan You are very right, it's more clean and easy to use `\w`, thank you.

Comment: @Jun Your answer is very correct. My answer have the scope to be generic as possible, because more emoji can appear in system sooner or later and i don't want to update my list every time.

Comment: How does this handle `Tricky test:123:grinning:`? (Should become `Tricky test:123` as `123` is not a emoij.)

Comment: @Dorus Very interesting test case, using `Regex.Replace` with lambda expression you can test that case `:numbers:` and skip it. When was the last time you wrote `something:32432:emoticon:`?

Comment: Well, I'm just obsessed over correctness. Anyway, I just hope people that use 856 emojis also use correct punctuation and insert spaces where they should.

Comment: @Dorus if they have only `:lettters_:` it's very easy to skip the rest of them. Better skip few cases than check over 856 hardcoded emoji. If you have another solution, please post it, maybe the bounty will go to you :D.

Comment: I really dont see the problem with going over 856 emoji, unless performance is really critical i could write up a answer using a tree format to store the emoji. This would give far superior performance compared to regex matching, but really not sure if it's needed. If performance is that crucial I can write it out and explain how to do it.

Comment: Been pondering over this for a few days, it probably wont be much better than using a `HashSet` as has already been suggested. Slightly easier is what fubo has already suggested. Also, you might be able to make your regex even simpler by adding a min and max length for the emoji. As in `:(\w{4,15}):` (where 4 and 15 should be length of the shortest and longest emoji code.)

Answer (score 16):

```
string Text = "Hello:grinning: , how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet:";
```

i would solve it that way

```
List<string> Emoj = new List<string>() { ":kissing_heart:", ":bouquet:", ":grinning:" };
Emoj.ForEach(x => Text = Text.Replace(x, string.Empty));
```

**UPDATE** - refering to Detail's Comment

Another approach: replace only existing Emojs

```
List<string> Emoj = new List<string>() { ":kissing_heart:", ":bouquet:", ":grinning:" };
var Matches = Regex.Matches(Text, @":(\w*):").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
Emoj.Intersect(Matches).ToList().ForEach(x => Text = Text.Replace(x, string.Empty));
```

But i'm not sure if it's that big difference for such short chat-strings and it's more important to have code that's easy to read/maintain. OP's question was about reducing redundancy `Text.Replace().Text.Replace()` and not about the most efficient solution.

Comment: In my mind the OP was going to run this over a large file, that probably contains all 856 emoij anyway, so your second approach would  be slower. If he plans to use it on just a short line, the performance increase can never be enough to justify the reduced readability.

Comment: that's wrong, the first post sayes _I read a content of strings from a messenger_

Answer (score 8):

I would use a combination of some of the techniques already suggested. Firstly, I'd store the 800+ emoji strings in a database and then load them up at runtime. Use a HashSet to store these in memory, so that we have a O(1) lookup time (very fast). Use Regex to pull out all potential pattern matches from the input and then compare each to our hashed emoji, removing the valid ones and leaving any non-emoji patterns the user has entered themselves...

```
public class Program
{
    //hashset for in memory representation of emoji,
    //lookups are O(1), so very fast
    private HashSet<string> _emoji = null;

    public Program(IEnumerable<string> emojiFromDb)
    {
        //load emoji from datastore (db/file,etc)
        //into memory at startup
        _emoji = new HashSet<string>(emojiFromDb);
    }

    public string RemoveEmoji(string input)
    {
        //pattern to search for
        string pattern = @":(\w*):";
        string output = input;

        //use regex to find all potential patterns in the input
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

        //only do this if we actually find the 
        //pattern in the input string...
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            //refine this to a distinct list of unique patterns 
            IEnumerable<string> distinct = 
                matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct();

            //then check each one against the hashset, only removing
            //registered emoji. This allows non-emoji versions 
            //of the pattern to survive...
            foreach (string match in distinct)
                if (_emoji.Contains(match))
                    output = output.Replace(match, string.Empty);
        }

        return output;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program(new string[] { ":grinning:", ":kissing_heart:", ":bouquet:" });
        string output = program.RemoveEmoji("Hello:grinning: :imadethis:, how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet: This is:a:strange:thing :to type:, but valid :nonetheless:");
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Which results in:

*Hello :imadethis:, how are you? Are you fine? This is:a:strange:thing :to type:,
 but valid :nonetheless:*

Comment: This is not very effective. `output.Replace(...)` will have to search the entire string a second time. Replace itself will already replace all instances of the emoij, but your matcher might match the same emoij a second time, causing Replace to be ran a second time unneeded.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've refined the list of matches into a collection of distinct (unique) strings before looping through them

Comment: You have done an exceptional job. I really had a hard time choosing between your answer and @Dorus answer, you both deserver my bounty.

Answer (score 7):

You do not have to replace all 856 emoji's. You only have to replace those that appear in the string. So have a look at:

[Finding a substring using C# with a twist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822900/finding-a-substring-using-c-sharp-with-a-twist)

Basically you extract all tokens ie the strings between : and : and then replace those with string.Empty()

If you are concerned that the search will return strings that are not emojis such as :some other text: then you could have a hash table lookup to make sure that replacing said found token is appropriate to do.

Answer (score 5):

Finally got around to write something up. I'm combining a couple previously mentioned ideas, with the fact we should only loop over the string once. Based on those requirement, this sound like the perfect job for `Linq`.

You should probably cache the `HashSet`. Other than that, this has O(n) performance and only goes over the list once. Would be interesting to benchmark, but this could very well be the most efficient solution.

The approach is pretty straight forwards.

- First load all Emoij in a `HashSet` so we can quickly look them up.
- Split the string with `input.Split(':')` at the `:`.
- Decide if we keep the current element.

  - If the last element was a match, keep the current element.
  - If the last element was no match, check if the current element matches.

    - If it does, ignore it. (This effectively removes the substring from the output).
    - If it doesn't, append `:` back and keep it.
- Rebuild our string with a `StringBuilder`.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ISet<string> emojiList = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "kissing_heart", "bouquet", "grinning" });

            Console.WriteLine("Hello:grinning: , ho:w: a::re you?:kissing_heart:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet:".RemoveEmoji(':', emojiList));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string RemoveEmoji(this string input, char delimiter, ISet<string> emojiList)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            input.Split(delimiter).Aggregate(true, (prev, curr) =>
            {
                if (prev)
                {
                    sb.Append(curr);
                    return false;
                }
                if (emojiList.Contains(curr))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                sb.Append(delimiter);
                sb.Append(curr);
                return false;
            });
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I did something cool using the [Rx library](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET), but then realized `Aggregate` is the `IEnumerable` counterpart of `Scan` in Rx, thus simplifying the code even more.

Comment: You were very concentrated on making it fast, and you succeed.

Comment: @adricadar It was a bit of a obsession yes :-)

Answer (score 3):

If efficiency is a concern and to avoid processing "false positives", consider rewriting the string using a StringBuilder while skipping the special emoji tokens:

```
static HashSet<string> emojis = new HashSet<string>()
{
    "grinning",
    "kissing_heart",
    "bouquet"
};

static string RemoveEmojis(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int length = input.Length;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int colonIndex = input.IndexOf(':');

    while (colonIndex >= 0 && startIndex < length)
    {
        //Keep normal text
        int substringLength = colonIndex - startIndex;
        if (substringLength > 0)
            sb.Append(input.Substring(startIndex, substringLength));

        //Advance the feed and get the next colon
        startIndex = colonIndex + 1;
        colonIndex = input.IndexOf(':', startIndex);

        if (colonIndex < 0) //No more colons, so no more emojis
        {
            //Don't forget that first colon we found
            sb.Append(':');
            //Add the rest of the text
            sb.Append(input.Substring(startIndex));
            break;
        }
        else //Possible emoji, let's check
        {
            string token = input.Substring(startIndex, colonIndex - startIndex);

            if (emojis.Contains(token)) //It's a match, so we skip this text
            {
                //Advance the feed
                startIndex = colonIndex + 1;
                colonIndex = input.IndexOf(':', startIndex);
            }
            else //No match, so we keep the normal text
            {
                //Don't forget the colon
                sb.Append(':');

                //Instead of doing another substring next loop, let's just use the one we already have
                sb.Append(token);
                startIndex = colonIndex;
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> inputs = new List<string>()
    {
        "Hello:grinning: , how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet:",
        "Tricky test:123:grinning:",
        "Hello:grinning: :imadethis:, how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet: This is:a:strange:thing :to type:, but valid :nonetheless:"
    };

    foreach (string input in inputs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In  <- " + input);
        Console.WriteLine("Out -> " + RemoveEmojis(input));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\nPress enter to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Outputs:

```
In  <- Hello:grinning: , how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet:
Out -> Hello , how are you? Are you fine?

In  <- Tricky test:123:grinning:
Out -> Tricky test:123

In  <- Hello:grinning: :imadethis:, how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet: This is:a:strange:thing :to type:, but valid :nonetheless:
Out -> Hello :imadethis:, how are you? Are you fine? This is:a:strange:thing :to type:, but valid :nonetheless:
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code I put up below I think using this function your problem will be solved.

```
        string s = "Hello:grinning: , how are you?:kissing_heart: Are you fine?:bouquet:";

        string rmv = ""; string remove = "";
        int i = 0; int k = 0;
    A:
        rmv = "";
        for (i = k; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(s[i]) == ":")
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < s.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(s[j]) != ":")
                    {
                        rmv += s[j];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        remove += rmv + ",";
                        i = j;
                        k = j + 1;
                        goto A;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        string[] str = remove.Split(',');
        for (int x = 0; x < str.Length-1; x++)
        {
            s = s.Replace(Convert.ToString(":" + str[x] + ":"), "");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use extension method like this:

```
public static class Helper
{
   public static string MyReplace(this string dirty, char separator)
    {
        string newText = "";
        bool replace = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < dirty.Length; i++)
        {
            if(dirty[i] == separator) { replace = !replace ; continue;}
            if(replace ) continue;
            newText += dirty[i];
        }
        return newText;
    }
```

}

Usage:

richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text.MyReplace(':');

This method show be better in terms of performance compare to one with Regex

Comment: Indeed, you save some `ms` but it removes everything between ':everything:'.

Comment: Correct, but it is exactly what it supposed to do; If you use Regex.Replace with pattern that matches all text starting and ending with ':' the result would be the same; But Regex is too slow at times... (especially if one don't know how to use it properly)

Answer (score 0):

I would split the text with the ':' and then build the string excluding the found emoji names.

```
        const char marker = ':';
        var textSections = text.Split(marker);

        var emojiRemovedText = string.Empty;

        var notMatchedCount = 0;
        textSections.ToList().ForEach(section =>
        {
            if (emojiNames.Contains(section))
            {
                notMatchedCount = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (notMatchedCount++ > 0)
                {
                    emojiRemovedText += marker.ToString();

                }
                emojiRemovedText += section;
            }
        });
```